# /var/www permissions have been changed with chmod -R 777

Tags: permissions

How do I revert back to the original settings for this directory?

If it is not possible to revert to original settings, will doing an upgrade to a newer version of Ubuntu server 12.04 correct the problem?

I am not experiencing problems but have read that it is not good to change the permissions on these directories

Regards
Benjamin

Answer (score 2):

The standard, default permissions that get assigned to files and directories by the server are normally;

Files = 644  and  Directories = 755

```
chmod 755 $(find /var/www -type d)

chmod 644 $(find /var/www -type f)
```